# Acer travel mate 4152ncli mouse is running in laptop undefined mouse behavior

Tags: drivers, bios, keyboard-layout, acer-travelmate

I am having some problem in my Acer travel mate 4152NCLI laptop. I have made a video of problem it can be seen on following link 
acer travelmate error https://youtu.be/7Z7bCqFLdKM
If you see the video something is happening due to which the cursor is moving up down without even my pressing the up or down key.
This is repeating when logged in I am unable to use the laptop because some random event gets clicked and the cursor is randomly moving up and down. This happened even when I entered BIOS.
So what should I check?
Here is error video 2
https://youtu.be/9_p7KWftTV8
I am trying to scroll down but it is not letting me scroll down.
Here is error video 3
I am trying to put my cursor at a position but it is automatically going up
https://youtu.be/sMXjsvdZKmY
See I am trying to click at bottom most line in paragraph but cursor is going upwards without my any click.
It has made use of laptop almost impossible.This laptop does not have a usb boot option so that I could have formatted it.

There is not much information in google about this laptop
https://www.google.com/search?q=travelmate+4152ncli&rlz=1C1RLNS_enIN856IN856&oq=travelmate+4152ncli&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.6843j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

error 4
https://youtu.be/JXPjHS6Wp2I

Comment: Have you tried another mouse, or just the touchpad?

Comment: I am just using this laptop no other mouse etc.Can touchpad be replaced?

Comment: Clean the touchpad. It's likely wet.

Comment: Actually this problem I am facing from many many days I have traveled with this laptop 1500 Kilometers and at the place before also this problem was there.Based on your suggestion USB mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by scanning keyboard on online keyboard check websites.However much could not be found except that insert key stopped working I could know only this much.Then I dwlownloaded keyboard tweak utility 
https://keytweak.en.softonic.com/

and disabled up arrow key and mapped insert key to use as up arrow key.