# finding the bios device drivers for acer 4152 travelmate

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, bios

I have a very old laptop.More than 10 years old.
Its model number is Acer Travelmate 4152NCLI,
unfortunately there are some problems in this laptop which I explained in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1491898/acer-travel-mate-4152ncli-mouse-is-running-in-laptop-undefined-mouse-behavior).
So I wanted to format the laptop but I could not search the device drivrs or BIOS so that if I re install Windows7 then I am able to install things again. 
This laptop does not have a boot from USB support (so I thought upgrading BIOS might help)

I could not locate it [here](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/IN/content/software) on website.So let me know if some one can help.
I use Windows7.
The CD ROM does not work.
See the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Many manufacturers are not supporting old BIOS because of the virus in hardware issue about a year and a half ago. So only newer machines are being supported. We are replacing machines six years old and older in most cases

Comment: Does it have a cd/dvd drive?

Comment: Yes it has cd drive

Comment: @Moab I updated the question the CD-DVD ROM does not work